# iPhone in airplane mode

Tags: iphone, geolocation

Suppose I, as an iPhone owner, have enabled **Control Center** access from the **Lock Screen**, and I have enabled the **GPS** features, to be able to trace the phone should it be stolen.

*Why did Apple engineers put the Airplane Mode button in the Control Center?* If someone steals the phone, they don't need to know the password to my phone. They can just put the phone in Airplane Mode and then all the GPS functionality is lost and I wouldn't be able to recover the phone. Isn't this a massive security problem?

[image: iPhone]

Answer (score 6):

Airplane mode is in the control center because it's much more convenient to get to it there than to go through a bunch of settings pages. Even if it weren't there, the same effect is easy enough to achieve by sticking the phone in a Faraday cage. Yes, it's slightly easier to do it with airplane mode there, but the extra risk is minor and the convenience is high. If it concerns you, just turn off Control Center on the lock screen, and know that someone can still use a Faraday cage to prevent GPS tracking. Calling this a "massive" security problem is more than a little overstating the case.

Comment: "_the same effect is easy enough to achieve by sticking the phone in a Faraday cage_" Not my iPhone; [it still transmits in airplane mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/333648/202217)…